# Rails 5+, 6, rbenv + passenger - permission denied for bin/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rbenv

Everythings goes well, passanger-status ? ok, 2 worker process of passenger but 500 server error bacause of:

```
  App 735 output: /bin/sh: 1: exec: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/bin/ruby: Permission denied
```

Does someone know what's going on? I spend 5 hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: "/root/.rbenv/" suggests that rbenv was installed as "root" and this "Permission denied" suggests passenger is running as some other user.

Comment: rbenv installing with root user is bad idea

Comment: i reinstall server and create user for rbenv ... I don't understand why default passenger user "nobody" doesn't work but ... thanks, I do not want to add user but this help.

Comment: please update the title to include something related to the problem (rather than a list of versions) like "server 500 error"